# How to inspect a numpy/pandas object, i.e. str() in R

Tags: python, r, numpy, pandas

When I use R, I can use `str()` to inspect objects which are a list of things most of the times.

I recently switched to Python for statistics and don't know how to inspect the objects I encounter. For example:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
heart = sm.datasets.heart.load_pandas().data
heart.groupby(['censors'])['age']
```

I want to investigate what kind of object is `heart.groupby(['censors'])` that allows me to add `['age']` at the end. However, `print heart.groupby(['censors'])` only tells me the type of the object, not its structure and what I can do with it.

So how do I get to understand the structure of numpy / pandas object, similar to `str()` in R?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get some insight into what you can do with a Python object, you can inspect it using a beefed-up Python console like IPython. In an IPython session, first put the object you want to look at into a variable:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
heart = sm.datasets.heart.load_pandas().data
h_grouped = heart.groupby(['censors'])
```

Then type out the variable name and double-tap Tab to bring up a list of the object's methods:

```
In [5]: h_grouped.<Tab><Tab>
# Shows the object's methods
```

A further benefit of the IPython console is you can quickly check the
help for any individual method by adding a `?`:

```
h_grouped.apply?
# Apply function and combine results 
# together in an intelligent way.
```

If you don't have IPython or a similar console, you can achieve something similar using `dir()`, e.g. `dir(h_grouped)`, although this will also list
the object's private methods which are generally not useful and shouldn't be
touched in regular use.

Comment: The double-tap Tab is a neat trick, but unfortunately in this case returns over 300 methods (What's more, I don't see `mean()` listed!). Let's say that I want to search if there's method related to "taking a mean", how would I do it?

Comment: `h_grouped.apply??` shows the code, if written in Python.

Comment: Sometimes I'll use `h_grouped.__<tab>` to see the 'hidden' attributes.

Comment: @Heisenberg ah yeah, sorry, because columns also become attributes of dataframes, if your dataframe has a lot of columns the tab-completion is less useful.

Comment: The question really isn't about inspecting *objects* but inspecting the dataframe.  str() in r produces: column type, first few entries, number of NANs/NA stuff like that

Answer (score 0):

```
type(heart.groupby(['censors'])['age'])
```

`type` will tell you what kind of object it is. At the moment you are grouping by a dimension and not telling pandas what to do with `age`. If you want the mean for example you could do:

```
heart.groupby(['censors'])['age'].mean()
```

This would take the mean of age by the group, and return a series.

Comment: But how do I know that I can append age to the groupby object like that?

Comment: Age is already part of the data frame, heart. You aren't appending it.

Comment: Sorry, I confusingly used the word "append". What I mean to ask is, given `heart.groupby(['censors'])`, how can I know that I can do `heart.groupby(['censors'])['age']` ? How can a beginner know about this kind of information by inspecting the structure (not just knowing the type) of an object?

Comment: The pandas docs are really quite good. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html for example gives examples of how to use the group by object, its methods and parameters etc.. It depends what you mean by structure I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the docs, but even in there it only list the parameters of the `groupby()` method, not a description of the object that it returns (except for a few examples.)

Answer (score 0):

The `groupby` is I think a red herring -- "age" is just a column name:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

heart = sm.datasets.heart.load_pandas().data
heart
#      survival  censors   age
#  0         15        1  54.3
#  ...

heart.keys()
#  Index([u'survival', u'censors', u'age'], dtype='object')
```